# error al cargar imagen almacenada en sql server

Tags: c#, picturebox

tengo una imagen almacenada en mi tabla tipo varbinarymax, la mayoria de imagenes si las puedo mostrar en mi picturebox pero las que son tomadas con camara digital y subidas a  la base de datos me marca el error:

```
parameter is not valid
```

Este es mi codigo que funciona con las demas imagenes descragadas de internet por ejemplo pero con las tomadas con camara digital no las puedo mostrar:

```
byte[] imagebyte = new byte[0];

 imagebyte = (byte[])readercoti[14];//aqui paso mis datos varbinarymax 

 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imagebyte, 0, imagebyte.Length);

ImgPic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);//aqui me sale el error
```

Asi es como mando la imagen a la base de datos:

```html
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rutaImagen);
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            bmp.Save(ms, bmp.RawFormat);
                            byteimage = ms.GetBuffer();  

SqlParameter imgparameter = comsem.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Binary);
                        imgparameter.Value = byteimage;
```

Comment: Prueba de subir una imagen que puedas ver a la base de datos y recuperarla. Así sabrás si el problema es que el formato de la imagen de la cámara digital no está soportado, o es que al enviar y recuperar de la BD se corrompe la imagen.

Comment: hay varias imagenes en la base de datos, la gran mayoria si la puedo recuperar pero solo las que toman con la camara no las puedo recuperar lo cual se me hace muy raro

Comment: Pues mira el formato de las imágenes de la cámara. Puedes probar cargando una directamente desde un fichero.

Comment: edite y agregue como subo la imagen

Comment: Pero la cuestión es que si esa lógica te funciona para determinadas imágenes, te debe funcionar para todas. El problema parecería que está en el formato de la imágen, no en de dónde la sacas.

Comment: buscando info me dice que  SqlDbType.Binary me dice  Un flujo de datos binarios de longitud fija que varía entre 1 y 8.000 bytes. las imagenes son de 2 a 3 MB, se a caso eso?